# How to select from two tables and display only what you want?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select from 2 different  tables.

In the first table I want to select all, but I will display only what I want.

In the second table I want to select only the profile picture but even if a user does not have a profile picture his data from the user table should be selected.

I am using inner joins. Below is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM
 tish_user INNER JOIN tish_images
 ON tish_user.user_id = tish_images.user_id
 WHERE tish_images.prof_image = 1
```

Comment: If respondents are going to suggest using an OUTER JOIN then adding a WHERE condition to the joined table is self-defeating.

Comment: I'm missing something @Strawberry.

Comment: Have you tried my downvoted solution?

Comment: @Jack your  edit is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
SELECT * FROM
tish_user, tish_images
WHERE tish_user.user_id = tish_images.user_id
AND
tish_images.prof_image = 1;
```

I think this might help you.

Cheers bro

Answer (score 2):

To select from two different tables, you should specify values from each table that you want, not using catch-all `*`. Using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN lets you connect the tables you are querying from on a single point. You can query any kind of relationship between the tables at that point.

This query will give you all the `userid`s in `tish_user` returning the matching `tish_images.prof_image` record if `prof_image` is 1, NULL otherwise.

```
SELECT 
    tish_user.user_id, 
    tish_images.prof_image 
FROM
    tish_user 
LEFT JOIN tish_images
ON tish_user.user_id = tish_images.user_id
AND tish_images.prof_image = 1
```

Comment: Is an explanation on the way?

Comment: (Trust me, I havent downvoted this. :) )But, you should provide some description, what is going on here.. or some link that will clear the doubts about the concept, if any, in questioner's mind.

Comment: This is wrong: SELECT x.* FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON y.a = x.a WHERE y.b = 'z';

Comment: This is right: SELECT x.* FROM x LEFT JOIN y ON y.a = x.a AND y.b = 'z'; – Strawberry 8 secs ago edit

Comment: @Strawberry Are you sure? We are in MySQL - I use this kind of query on a daily basis...

Comment: Why not try it for yourself? Stick up a SQLFIDDLE

Comment: @Strawberry http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b563/1/0 amiwrong? - I want my flippin' 2 rep back. ;]

Comment: Yes. You're wrong. The OP said he wanted ALL results from table 1.

Comment: I took that to mean columns, not records. How can you distinguish from the question details?

Comment: Nick, you're really missing something here. The LEFT JOIN in your fiddle has no effect. It's the same as using an INNER JOIN.

Comment: I concede. I see my mistake.

Comment: @Nicholas Pickering You understood the problem You solved the problem You deserved to be called a star

Comment: @Strawberry  Nic got it right and explained "To select from two different tables, you should specify values from each table that you want, not using catch-all " / So I did what he said and worked thanks 2 u 2

Comment: Yes - he corrected his answer so I gave him his "flippin' rep" back ;-)

Comment: I really owe @Strawberry the rep on this one. :] Did not foresee getting the accept on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) instead of `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM
tish_user LEFT JOIN tish_images
ON tish_user.user_id = tish_images.user_id
WHERE tish_images.prof_image = 1
```

**Explanation**

LEFT JOIN selects all rows in the left table, even if there are no entries in the right table (in which case the columns for the right table will be `NULL`)

Also check RIGHT JOIN, it does the same thing with the right side :)

Comment: ^ to explain why: LEFT JOIN keeps all the information on the left side of the 'LEFT JOIN' (in your case tish_user), so even if some rows in this table don't have a common index with the table from the right side it will still be displayed, with NULL values on the fields corresponding to the right side table.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I tried to explain the same thing, but probably not well enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 tish_user U
    LEFT JOIN tish_images I
 ON U.user_id = I.user_id
   AND = I.prof_image = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Suppose you want to display the userID, firstname and lastname from the tish_user table and the prof_image from the tish_images table.

```
  SELECT tish_user.userd_id, tish_user.firstname, tish_user.lastname, tish_images.prof_image
FROM tish_user tish_user LEFT JOIN tish_image tish_image ON tish_user.user_id=tish_images.user_id WHERE tish_image.prof_image=1
```

I think this will do.

Comment: Your contribution on the event is appreciated